# Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode?

Tags: angular, typescript

> projects/master-library-lib/src/lib/components/objects/objects.component.ts:11:14
>
> error NG3001: Unsupported private class ObjectsComponent. This class is visible to consumers via MasterLibraryLibModule ->
> ObjectsComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library
> entrypoint.
>
> 11 export class ObjectsComponent implements OnInit {

I've tried to give the exact declaration and specified path for the above error. However, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the file in the library entryFile (public-api.ts is the default one) can solve your issue.
Link to [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#getting-started)